# Why was the array type of formal parameter of a function converted to pointer?

Tags: c++

The output of the following function is "int *", which means the formal parameter is converted to a integer pointer. Is there any necessary reason for this design? Why can't we reserve the array type?

```
// the output is "int *"
#include<typeinfo>
void Func(int ar[5])
{
  printf("%s\n", typeid(ar).name();
}
int main()
{
  int ar[5];
  Func(ar);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264611/arguments-in-a-function-prototype/3264641#3264641

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any necessary reason for this design?

This is historical baggage from C. Supposedly <sup>[1](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)</sup> this was convenience as you can't pass arrays by-value anyway.

If you want to preserve the type, you can use a references or pointers:

```
void Func(int (&ar)[5]);
```

Or using template functions to accept an arbitrarily sized array:

```
template<std::size_t N> void Func(int (&ar)[N]);
```

Comment: @sbi: `template<typename T, std::size_t N> void func(T (&ar)[N])` is even better. :P

Comment: & @Prasoon: People often think of templates when they need something to work with different _types_, but usually forget about non-type template arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that this is called "the array decay" and there is a good discussion of it here:

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Using raw arrays in c++ is a little "c-style". True C++ adepts use std::vector, which has no decay and typing problems. Nevertheless, legacy code is full of raw arrays and "C++" compilers have to play under the "C" rules to provide compatibility.